# GWT hosted mode in multiproject maven setup

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have a multimodule maven setup for my project, made of 5 modules, which includes a GWT webapp.
It is also an eclipse multiproject workspace, so I created an additional project, only containing a pom, which lists the other projects (sibling on the file system) as children modules.
I'm also a new maven user, so I might be doing something wrong. =)

The gwt module uses the following plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <hostedWebapp>war</hostedWebapp>
    <runTarget>GWT.html</runTarget>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn package` on the pom project I get the expected behaviour: projects are build in the correct order, and the war is fine.
When I run `mvn gwt:run`, though, maven tries to find a gwt app on each module, failing on the first one (the parent) which doesn't even declare nor manage the gwt plugin.
If I run `mvn -fn gwt:run`, the build fails on each other project, finally finding a gwt app on the gwt module, and displaying it.

- How do I correctly run the app on hosted mode? Is this the correct behavior?

I do not want the GWT module to be the parent module (if it's possible), because the project has multiple target platforms, producing the gwt web frontend, a Java executable jar backend and in the future also an Android app, and shares most parts of the code (not only the model). Is a single pom structure recommended for such a setup, or am I failing at maven?

Are profiles what I need? If I do, should I declare the same profile id on each module? How would I prevent the trigger of `gwt:run` command on them anyway?

- What should the setup of such a project be? Is this the correct setup?

**Additional information**

Modules are

- `pom`: declares modules `model`, `logic`, `analyze`, `gwt`, `tests`
- `model`: no dependencies
- `logic`: no dependencies
- `analyze`: depends on `model`, `logic`
- `gwt`: depends on `model`, `logic`
- `tests`: depends on `model`, `logic`, `analyze`, `gwt` (contains global tests,
  not unit tests)

If I run `gwt:run` on the `gwt` module i get the error

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project
djjeck.gwt:djjeck.gwt:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Could not find artifact djjeck.model:djjeck.model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

This is from `djjeck.gwt/pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>djjeck.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>djjeck.model</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

A `com.model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is inside the war lib folder, both packed and unpacked, and also inside `djjeck.model/target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the webapp module and then run `mvn gwt:run`.

You may use profiles to speed up compilation time: one profile could only gwt compile for gecko and english +draftCompile for example.

Have a look at maven GWT plugin [multi-module setup](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html) if you're still having problems.

Comment: I get a `Could not resolve dependencies for project djjeck.gwt:djjeck.gwt:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
artifact djjeck.model:djjeck.model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. That jar is both inside the target folder of that project, and the lib folder of war. Where is it looking for it?

Comment: you have to put a dependency on the domain from the webapp module.

Comment: I think the dependency is set, this is why it's looking for the jar. I'm updating the OP.

Comment: model, logic and gwt all have <parent> defined? do mvn install in the parent first, then try gwt:run in gwt.

Comment: mvn install fixed it! Probably something got missing after moving some projects around =) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Will this setup allow you to change the domain and see the changes in GWT dev mode without doing a whole Maven install and restart of dev mode?

Answer (score 1):

As I was also struggling with GWT dev mode and a Maven project with multiple sub-modules/projects, I created an example and uploaded it to GitHub. You can find it at:

https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example

The readme on aboves page shows how to run it via Maven. Features of this example are:

- multiple modules
- not using GWT's embedded Jetty, but an own Tomcat7 server
- startup of Tomcat7 and GWT hosted mode possible via documented Maven commands

I hope this helps a bit to have at least a working example to start from.